# Why is virtualenv necessary?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am a beginner in Python.

I read *`virtualenv` is preferred during Python project development*.

I couldn't understand this point at all. Why is `virtualenv` preferred?

Comment: Do you know what virtualenv is what what it's uses are?

Comment: You may have multiple projects on your computer, each of which were built with a different version of Python.

Comment: yeh I know about virtualization. I got it. Thanks Tim and Alex

Comment: @RaiAmmadKhan Is it no necessary, but it helps. And it has nothing to do with virtualization in the form of virtual machines.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) keeps your Python packages in a virtual environment localized to your project, instead of forcing you to install your packages system-wide.

There are a number of benefits to this,

- the first and principle one is that you can have multiple virtulenvs, so you
  can have multiple sets of packages that for different projects, even
  if those sets of packages would normally conflict with one another. 
  For instance, if one project you are working on runs on Django 1.4
  and another runs on Django 1.6, virtualenvs can keep those projects
  fully separate so you can satisfy both requirements at once.
- the second, make it easy for you to release your project with its own dependent
  modules.Thus you can make it easy to create your requirements.txt
  file.
- the third, is that it allows you to switch to another installed python interpreter for that project*. Very useful (Think old 2.x scripts), but sadly not available in the now [built-in venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Note that virtualenv is about "virtual environments" but is *not* the same as "virtualization" or "virtual machines" (this is confusing to some).  For instance, VMWare is totally different from virtualenv.

Comment: This ignores the installation of multiple python interpreters, which also effectively can creates a localized environment.  What was implied, but is worth explicitly noting, is the same base interpreter is used across the virtual python environments.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real point to them in 2022, they are a mechanism to accomplish what C#, Java, Node, and many other ecosystems have done for years without virtual environments.

Projects need to be able to specify their package and interpreter dependencies in isolation from other projects. Virtual Environments are a fine but legacy solution to that issue. (Vs a config file which specifies interpreter version and local `__pypackages__`)

[pep 582](https://peps.python.org/pep-0582/) aims to address this lack of functionality in the python ecosystem.

Comment: pep 582 is in rejected state as of now.

Answer (score 1):

A Virtual Environment, put simply, is an isolated working copy of Python which allows you to work on a specific project without worry of affecting other projects.

For example, you can work on a project which requires Django 1.3 while also maintaining a project which requires Django 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

**VirtualEnv** helps you create a **Local Environment(not System wide) Specific to the Project** you are working upon.

Hence, As you **start working on Multiple projects**, your projects would have **different Dependencies (e.g different Django versions)** hence you would need a different virtual Environment for each Project. VirtualEnv does this for you.

As, you are using VirtualEnv.. Try **VirtualEnvWrapper** : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper

It **provides some utilities** to create switch and remove virtualenvs easily, e.g:

1. **`mkvirtualenv <name>`**: To create a new Virtualenv
2. **`workon <name>`** : To use a specified virtualenv

and some others

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are working on multiple projects, one project requires certain version of python and other project requires some other version. In case you are not working on virtual environment both projects will access the same version installed in your machine locally which in case can give error for one.

While in case of virtual environment you are creating a new instance of your machine where you can store all the libraries, versions separately. Each time you can create a new virtual environment and work on it as a new one.