How to change "Recommended environment" in Visual Studio Code
In Visual Studio Code, whenever I'm prompted to choose an environment, there is a "recommended" one or "favourite" one. But it's not the one I would like to see there (I would like another virtual environment* to get there).
E.g.:

I've looked everywhere. How can I change this and select which one should be "recommended"?
* added virtual environment to this sentence because apparently someone said it's bad to recommend a non-virtual-environment

what do you mean by another one? do you mean python from virtual environment or alt installed python?

As far as I know, VS Code will "recommend" the newest version of Python you have installed. Why do you want to change this? It's just a suggestion and shouldn't affect anything.

It currently suggests a virtual environment (for some reason I don't know) and I would like to have my default Python 3.12.5 as suggested

It is already suggesting 3.12.5 and VSC won't recommend global environment as it is dangerous to configure your project at system-wide (global environment). Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948317/why-is-virtualenv-necessary

@AmadeuszLiu How can I make VSC recommend one virtual environment in particular then?

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows You can not change it as it is just a recommendation and as Riggles stated it will only suggest newest version and will not affect anything.

@AmadeuszLiu Ah so they didn't make an option to change the recommendation? That's unfortunate :/

@AmadeuszLiu Should I still make a feature request even if the feature exists? Sorry I'm new to programming that might sound like a stupid question

There are (at least) two things to change to have a menu like this:


activate your virtualenv first, and then launch code from the same shell.

    source ./venv/bin/activate
    code .


Preferences->Extensions->Python:

    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/bin/python"

